# Run on Eclipse (The selection can't be launched)

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to run my file; however, it says the selection can't be launched. Also, it says the word 'args' is not correctly spelled. But I still don't understand.

Here is my code.

```
public class Exercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      char x = 'a';
      char y = 'c';
      System.out.println(++x);
    }
}
```

Comment: the code inside your main works. paste your error.

Comment: How are you trying to run the code?

Comment: I just clicked on the icon which means running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Spelling and 
change the spell check options to suit your needs (most likely by 
disabling the feature entirely)

Comment: This should be a comment